Why did the Apollo 13 tank #2 have a heater and a vacuum?
While reading the accident report of Apollo 13, I came across this diagram:


Diagram by NASA

The report was just explaining the SM oxygen tank, and I have two questions looking at his diagram.

Why is there a heater in an O2 tank?

The report explains how a "Vacuum between the shells prevent heat leak", Where exactly is the vacuum present and how does it prevent a heat leak?



tl;dr

The heaters are there to control the pressure in the tank
The tank is of double-walled construction with a vacuum between, like a Thermos bottle, because the oxygen is at cryogenic temperature

The power reactants on Apollo were stored at conditions that made them supercritical fluids. The critical pressure for O2 is ~ 730 psi, the Apollo tanks were at ~ 900 psi.


A supercritical fluid is any substance at a temperature and pressure above its critical point, where distinct liquid and gas phases do not exist.


The lack of distinct phases is important for systems like the Apollo
and Shuttle cryo systems. The heat transfer properties of gaseous O2
and liquid O2 are quite different - if the fluid was allowed to have
gas bubbles in it, hot spots could occur on the heater surfaces
adjacent to bubbles, which could be disastrous in the pure O2
environment.
Keeping the O2 and H2 cryogens for the fuel cells at supercritical
conditions is a smart design for several reasons.

There is no concern about keeping the fluids at the tank outlet. The supercritical fluids occupy the entire tank volume.
It's simple to manage the properties of the fluids - it can be done with a relatively straightforward heater / pressure sensor control
system.
No pumps or other devices are needed to expel the fluids, the high pressure in the tanks does that for you.
No slosh dynamics because no liquid/vapor boundary (h/t to Tristan for the comment, also mentioned in the reference here)


The heaters were used to maintain the pressure in the tanks. When enough fluid was drawn out to cause the pressure to drop a certain amount, the pressure control circuits turned the heater on, dumping energy into the fluid, and raising its pressure back up. The system was designed to keep the pressure high enough so that the fluid was always maintained in the supercritical state.
The Apollo system turned the heaters on when the pressure dropped below 865 psi and turned them off when the pressure rose above 935 psi.
This drawing from the Command Module Systems Handbook shows how the heater control system is controlled by the pressure at the tank outlet.
You can see how a pressure switch output (yellow) actuates the motor contactor in the "oxygen assembly". When the contactor is closed, power is supplied to the heaters (red).

This diagram (blue) also shows that the oxygen is at cryogenic temperature, -297 deg F.  This extremely cold temperature is why the tanks were double-walled with a vacuum between, to maintain the fluid properties. (The vehicle spent a lot of time in the vacuum of space, but it also spent a lot of time on the ground being prepped for launch).

Each dewar consists of an inner pressure vessel and an outer vacuum shell with evacuated multilayer insulation in the annulus between the two concentric spheres.

The tanks were inside the Service Module as shown here.

Sources

Why would oxygen be stored as a super critical fluid?
What does "stirring tanks" mean?
Command Module Systems Handbook CSM 114
Apollo Operations Handbook Block II Spacecraft
Apollo Experience Report - The Cryogenic Storage System


Maybe you can address also the second sub-question explicitly (about the vacuum)?

@Ludo thanks! Just noticed that myself and adding it now.

Thamk you!, seems far more accurate.

@Aerospace_Nerd these supercritical fluids are non-intuitive and confusing. Just look at the wrong answers posted here and at the links.
